# Copy the dns hierarchy

Tags: dns, iteration, bind

for an university project I try to copy the complete DNS Hierarchy into a few Docker Container.
To create a DNS Server in a container and get a valid DNS response is no problem anymore. But I've discovered problems as I try to make iterative queries.

The final version should work like this:

1. Client1 ask Resolver1 about hello.example.com
2. Instead to ask the DNS Root servers in the internet, the resolver is configured to ask my local server root1 about the ".com"-Zone.
3. root1 should now respond with the ip of root2 which is responsible for the .com-Zone
4. Resolver1 now asks root2 about hello.example.com.
5. root2 answers with the ip of root3 which is responsible for the "example.com"-zone.
6. Resolver1 now asks root3 about hello...., gets the right ip and send it back to client1

The complete Network has no internet connection.

I already reached the possibility to create a delegated sub-domain. But this is done with the root1 as slave for the ".com"-Zone. So this is not iterative, because root1 receives a copy of root2 zone file and with this is able to answer the DNS-request itself without the help of root2.

Atm im not sure which kind of server I need. The most google results I receive are the "autoritative-only DNS Server". But is this really the right kind of server for a Root-DNS-Server?

My main problem is to inform the "."-Zone DNS where he can find the server with the ".com"-Zone on it. In which configuration file i need to specify this?

I use bind for the DNS

Thanks and best regards
Franz

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

In the name.conf use the type "forward".

e.g. for the .com auth server:

```
zone "example.com" in {
   type forward;
   forwarders {<ip of auth server for example.com zone>;};
};
```